# overridePendingTransition() is not always working

Tags: android, webview, overridependingtransition

I have tried to add self defined animation for transition between the activities, but the animation is not getting overridden every time.

Sometimes the default animation is been shown and sometimes the animation which I have defined.
Please check if the reason can be tracked.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);


    wv1=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    wv1.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
    wv1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv1.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    wv1.loadUrl(url);
}
```

Comment: Instead of define `OverridePendingTransition` before `setContentView` define when you are writing code for `startactivity`.

Answer (score 0):

try to this where you can go next activity insted before a setContentView..

```
 Intent intent= new Intent(youractivity.this, nextactivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
```